# Are the expressions arr and &arr same for an array of 10 integers?

Tags: c

I came across this problem while taking the online quiz when i tested it in the online ide(Geeks For Geeks) in C language it actually giving the same result but in the test its answer was False.

```sh
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int arr[2] = {1,2};
    printf("%d %d",arr,&arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
-1134751264 -1134751264
```

Comment: The pointer value is the same, although the type is different.

Comment: It's better to print pointers with `%p`.

Comment: Note that the values of the pointers are _equivalent_, though do not need to be the same binary pattern nor size.  Commonly they are.

Comment: The compiler you are using is assuming you are wanting the pointer to the array given you haven't referred to an array element. &arr[0] would also give you the same result, but &arr[1] would give you a different result. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The values of the pointers are the same, but they have different types: `a` is an `int [2]` and `&a` is an `int (*)[2]`.

Other than the type difference, there's only one variation: If you add one to `&a`, it points to the next array of five `int`s after `a`. However, if you add one to `a`, it points to the next `int` after `*a`.